# How to edit passed data from parent to child component in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I have parent component with all teams and child component for displaying each of team in box using *ngFor and @Input. All child components are displayed fine but when I want to change each of them opening modal I always get the data from first object in array of teams.

**team.component.html**

```
<app-team-box *ngFor="let team of teams" [team]="team"></app-team-box>
```

**team-box.component.html**

```
<div class="ibox"> 
  <div class="ibox-title">
    <h5>{{this.team.name}}</h5>
    <a class="btn btn-xs" (click)="openEditTeamModal(this.team)">Edit</a>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="edit_team_modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <form role="form" (ngSubmit)="editTeam()" novalidate>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="this.team">
          <label>Team name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="this.team.name" #name="ngModel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**team-box.component.ts**

```
export class TeamBoxComponent implements OnInit {   
  @Input() team;

  constructor(private teamService: TeamService) {}

  openEditTeamModal(selectedTeam): void {
    this.team = selectedTeam;
    $("#edit_team_modal").modal();
    $(".modal").appendTo("html");
  }

  editTeam(): void {
    this.teamService.update(this.team).subscribe((team: Response) => {
      $("#edit_team_modal").modal("hide");
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is when I change first one everything is fine, modal is populated with name and after changing it's get saved. But when I click on edit button for example second team, in modal I get the data for first team. Why this.team is always referencing to first object in array of teams?

Comment: what do the `[team]` directive??

Comment: @KenrySanchez  Every team from *ngFor is passed using that [team] to child component.

Comment: so, the problem is there...

Comment: You are showing and hiding the same modal when u click edit.  $("#edit_team_modal").modal("hide") or $("#edit_team_modal").modal("show"); will hide and show the same modal. each modal you open should have a uniqueid.

Comment: @Subhashini thank you! It's working now.